# How to write product as a nested sums

Tags: summation

I'm required to write $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1-j_{i})$ as a nested sum, where $j_{ll} \neq j_{k}$ if $u \neq k$.

I undestand I'd get something in the form of $1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{j_{i}}+...+(-1)^n\prod\limits_{i=1}^nj_{i}$ but I don't know how I could write this as k-nested sums, in the form $\sum^{(k)} (expression)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I prefer to transform products to sums is:
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)=\sum_{I\subseteq [1,n]}\prod_{i\in I}a_i \tag{1}$$
the sum is taken over all subsets of $[1,n]$ for example:
$$\prod_{i=1}^2(1+a_i)=\prod_{i\in \emptyset}a_i+\prod_{i\in\{1\}}a_i+\prod_{i\in\{2\}}a_i+\prod_{i\in\{1,2\}}a_i=1+a_1+a_2+a_1a_2$$
And your product can be deduced from the formula $(1)$:
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)=\sum_{I\subseteq [1,n]}(-1)^{|I|}\prod_{i\in I}a_i $$
where $|I|$ denotes the cardinal of the set $I$

There is other notation other then $1$ to transform the product to a sum, mainly $$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)=1+\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k\leq n}\prod_{i=1}^ka_i \tag{2}$$

where the sum is taken over all ordered tuples $i_1<i_2<\cdots$ and your product will become using this notation:
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)=1+\sum_{1\leq k,1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k\leq n}(-1)^k\prod_{i=1}^ka_i $$

As an practical example in which there is the two formulas you can see the [principale of inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement)